# How to query AWS DynamoDB

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I wasn't able to find a complete example that clearly demonstrates how to query items of a DynamoDB table.

- The [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-dynamodb/interfaces/querycommandinput.html) do not specify which property to use (I am guessing a combination of `ExpressionAttributeValues` and `KeyConditionExpression`).
- The [other documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/dynamodb-example-query-scan.html) uses an outdated library `aws-sdk`
- The explanation [here](https://www.mischianti.org/2021/06/08/dynamodb-javascript-sdk-v2-v3-query-6/) is convoluted, extremely verbose and unclear.
- And, my preferred resource, [the examples repo](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javascriptv3/example_code/dynamodb/src/movies/queryTable.js), do not tie the explanation with a working example.

Lets suppose my table contains the following elements:

```
| Primary Key | Sort Key             |
|-------------|----------------------|
| **pk**      | **sk**               |
| fruit       | available-pear       |
| fruit       | eaten-apple          |
| fruit       | available-watermelon |
| fruit       | eaten-grape          |
| desert      | eaten-apple-pie      |
```

I would like to query (not scan) the table by only the available fruits.

I can't even query all the fruits.

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';

let dynamoClient = new DynamoDBClient({ region: process.env.REGION });

const command = new QueryCommand({
  // The tableName is correct and verified against the CF template
  TableName: tableName,
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':pk': { S: 'fruit' },
  },
  // I tryied all these variations
  // and also tryied removing ExpressionAttributeValues
  KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :pk',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :fruit',
});
const response = dynamoClient.send(command);

console.log('RESPONSE:');
console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
```

Gives me an empty response

```bash
INFO    RESPONSE:
INFO    {}
```

Any help is much appreciated,

Comment: What about `await dynamoClient.send(command)` (It's a promise)? - The parameters didn't change for the new library, it's still the same complicated mess. Are the names of your primary & sort keys `pk` and `sk`? (`ExpressionAttributeNames` would be used to make that variable). But `KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :XYZ'` is fine when you have `ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':XYZ': {..expected value...}}`. The attribute values replace values mentioned by name in conditions.

Comment: ‍♂️ `await` was missing. Yes my parameters are named `pk` and `sk`. Thanks, it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query all fruit:

```js
const command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'pk = :pk',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pk': { S: 'fruit' }},
});
```

Query available fruit:

```js
const command = new QueryCommand({
    TableName: tableName,
    KeyConditionExpression: '#pk = :pk AND begins_with(#sk, :sk)',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#pk': 'pk', '#sk': 'sk' }, // optional names substitution
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { ':pk': { S: 'fruit' }, ':sk': { S: 'available' } },
});
```

`send` returns a Promise.  Make sure to `await` it, as @zapl says:

```js
const response = await client.send(command);
```